# Download dependencies from Ivy.xml

Tags: ant, intellij-idea, dependencies, ivy

I have an ant project with ivy dependencies in it. Unfortunately my Intelij IDEA does not understend ivy dependencies. But ant builds project well. I want to download all dependencies to one folder and add jars explicitly to project.

How can i download all dependencies automatically?

---

As described here http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ant.html
During ant build ivy dependencies downloads to "cache". If i'll found this cache path i can took jars from there.

Comment: There is a plugin for Ivy called [IvyIDEA](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=3612). Doesn't that plugin solve your problems?

Comment: Yes i have this plugin, but it does not work or i wrongly configured it. But it can't see external classes.

Comment: I found IvyDependencyImporter. http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=141 But it doesn't work well.  I have installed it but button "import from ivy.xml" did not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what ant is doing. If its a well written ant script you'll find (do an `ant -p -v`) targets specifically for retrieving the ivy dependencies. Also you may inspect the `build.xml` and watch out for `retrieve` tasks probably in the `ivy` namespace.

Comment: Found the solution! Afte executing ant -p -v i found task, resolve_ivy. All my libraries was retrieved to ../lib dir. Thanks for helping